# Weird Shared Preference Behaviour

Tags: android

I have a login Activity where user sends login credentials to the server. On getting the response, I save the session variable (a JWT) in sharedpreferences and load the `LoggedIn Activity`. On reaching `LoggedIn Activity`, if I try to access the `jwt` it is not there!. Contrary to that, if I close the app and since jwt was saved in the `SharedPreference` I get redirected directly to the `loggedIn Activity` and now I can access the `jwt`. Why is this weird behavior going on?

Comment: i just faced with same issue, the problem was i was using a static method to save,encrypt shareprefs, i removed the encryption and removed static method ,now its working fine

Comment: @Redman I have an inherited class to deal with SharedPreferences and I am not using any static method to save the jwt.

Comment: It is hard to say without code. Maybe you only forgot to update your object, when you go to LoggedIn Activity. Or, did you try to commit changes immediately to the preferences?

Comment: Or you're using the activity specific shared preferences instead of the app-wide one

Comment: I have an app-wide shared preference and just after I receive `jwt` from backend I save it and commit it.